# Should this design be an STI or separate models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ive got an app where users can upload media: song, video, photos. I was thinking of having an STI called medium. Song, Video and Photo inherit from Medium.

Or should I have Song, Video and Photo as separate classes / models?

I also have a Comment model. If I go with an STI approach, then the Comment model would only need the medium_id as the FK.

If I go with separate classes, then my Comment model would have to be polymorphic. I guess both approaches work. But which one should be more considered over the other? Second, are there any advantages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have several requirements that overlap a lot in terms of data being captured, context for presentation, and relationships, you may want to go with STI. Your example here is one of them.

I find STI is often easier to manage when you're dealing with several things that are often aggregated and presented as if they are interchangeable. For instance, a list of most recently uploaded "media" would contain all of your types and could be sorted or filtered as required.

It's also not uncommon to have a polymorphic relationship on a Comment class so that anything can be commented on. The only down-side to this is that polymorphic relationships are harder to join and validate on a database level, so they will always be a tiny bit slower.

The more database-friendly approach is to make Comment act as a tree or list, and then have your Media model `belong_to` a root, placeholder comment, and the actual comment contents goes into children.

Comment: Lets say I have an Event class as well. Event has columns such as: Time, Date, Street, City, Country, etc. All these columns have nothing to do with Song, Video, and Photo. Should an STI approach still suffice?

Comment: If they're completely unrelated, you may not want to STI that in there, too. It's kind of a subjective call, but often if it diverges completely you should break it out separately.